# MongoDB: add or update items with nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, mongodb, multidimensional-array

I have a document with the following data:

```
Chest: {
    ChestID: 400, // Chest ID is unique
    Items: [{
        ItemID: 200, //Item ID unique too
        ItemIndexes: ['aaa10', 'bbb20'] // indexes should not be repeated
    }]
}
```

I tried to do this but I can't find a way to make it work:

```
public async appendItems(chestId: number, items: Array < ChestItem > ) {
    const tokensIds = items.map(item => item.tokenId)
    // bidimensional array [][]
    const tokenIndexes = items.map(item => item.indexesAsArray)

    await this.raw.updateOne({
        ChestID: chestId
    }, {
        $push: {
            "Items.$[item].token_indexes": {
                // in that bidimensional array there can be repeated indexes
                $each: tokenIndexes,
                position: "$"
            }
        }
    }, {
        arrayFilters: [{
            "item.token_id": {
                $in: tokensIds
            }
        }],
    })
}
```

So I want to do the following:

First I have to find the chest id, then I have to find the items id, then if the item id exists, just add new indexes ( there can be no more than 1 repeating index ) if it doesn't add the item.